# Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: Object/factory with type NavigationService is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart

I currently upgrade a very old flutter application developped by another developper.

After upgading dependencies, correct null safety problems and correct gradle problems, i first build application.

But the application hang at startup with this error:

> E/flutter ( 8836): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)]
> Unhandled Exception: 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed
> assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory
> with  type NavigationService is not registered inside GetIt.
> E/flutter ( 8836): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance();
> instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance; E/flutter ( 8836): Did you forget
> to register it?) E/flutter ( 8836): #0
> _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61) E/flutter ( 8836): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew
> (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5) E/flutter ( 8836): #2
> _GetItImplementation._findFactoryByNameAndType (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:372:7) E/flutter ( 8836): #3
> _GetItImplementation.get (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:393:29) E/flutter ( 8836): #4      _GetItImplementation.call
> (package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart:430:12) E/flutter ( 8836): #5
> new MyOrganizationViewModel
> (package:politeia_france/ui/views/my_organizations/my_organizations_viewmodel.dart:14:55)
> E/flutter ( 8836): #6      GetItInjectableX.init
> (package:politeia_france/app/locator.config.dart:63:51) E/flutter (
> 8836): #7      setupLocator
> (package:politeia_france/app/locator.dart:16:17) E/flutter ( 8836): #8
> main (package:politeia_france/main.dart:29:9) E/flutter ( 8836): #9
> _runMain. (dart:ui/hooks.dart:131:23) E/flutter ( 8836): #10     _delayEntrypointInvocation.
> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:297:19) E/flutter ( 8836): #11
> _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)

Problem is with getIt initialisation. GetIt is initalized with a generated dart file which is generated with `injectable_generator`.

pubspec.yaml configuration:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
...

  get_it: ^7.2.0
  injectable: ^2.1.0
...

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.12.0
  build_runner: ^2.3.3
  json_serializable: ^6.6.1
  auto_route_generator: ^5.0.3
  injectable_generator: ^2.1.2
  hive_generator: ^2.0.0
  ferry_generator: ^0.8.0+1
```

locator.dart:

```
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:politeia_france/app/locator.config.dart';

GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

@InjectableInit(preferRelativeImports: false)
Future<void> setupLocator() async {

  await locator.init(
    environment: '',
    environmentFilter: null,
  );

}
```

main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  if (kReleaseMode) {
    debugPrint = (String? message, {int? wrapWidth}) {};
  }

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
      statusBarColor: Colors.blue,
      statusBarBrightness: Brightness.dark,
      systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.blue));

  await setupLocator();

  debugPrint('>>>>>>>>>> Locator setup done');

  final AppService _appService = locator<AppService>();

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) async {
    debugPrint('>>>>>>>>>> Orientation fixed');
    await SentryFlutter.init(
      (options) {
        options.dsn =
            'https://456ac564d@o8974564.ingest.sentry.io/56987445';
      },
      appRunner: () {
        debugPrint('>>>>>>>>>> Sentry initialized');
        _appService.initApp();
        debugPrint('>>>>>>>>>> appService init done, run App');
        return runApp(MyApp());
      },
    );
  });
}
```

Generated locator.config.dart:

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

// **************************************************************************
// InjectableConfigGenerator
// **************************************************************************

// ignore_for_file: no_leading_underscores_for_library_prefixes
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart' as _i1;
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart' as _i2;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/api.dart' as _i3;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/app.dart' as _i4;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/my_organizations.dart' as _i7;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/my_participations.dart' as _i9;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/notifications_badges.dart' as _i10;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/settings.dart' as _i20;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/surveys.dart' as _i22;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/text_to_speech.dart' as _i23;
import 'package:politeia_france/services/third_party_services_modules.dart'
    as _i25;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/my_organizations/my_organizations_search_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i8;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/my_organizations/my_organizations_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i6;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/onboarding/onboarding_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i11;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/organisation/organization_alerts_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i12;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/participations/participations_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i14;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/posts/posts_viewmodel.dart' as _i13;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/questions/question_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i15;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/questions/questions_list_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i16;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/reports/report_create_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i17;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/reports/report_viewmodel.dart' as _i18;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/reports/reports_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i19;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/surveys/surveys_list_viewmodel.dart'
    as _i21;
import 'package:politeia_france/ui/views/user/user_viewmodel.dart' as _i24;
import 'package:stacked_services/stacked_services.dart'
    as _i5; // ignore_for_file: unnecessary_lambdas

// ignore_for_file: lines_longer_than_80_chars
extension GetItInjectableX on _i1.GetIt {
  // initializes the registration of main-scope dependencies inside of GetIt
  _i1.GetIt init({
    String? environment,
    _i2.EnvironmentFilter? environmentFilter,
  }) {
    final gh = _i2.GetItHelper(
      this,
      environment,
      environmentFilter,
    );
    final thirdPartyServicesModule = _$ThirdPartyServicesModule();
    gh.lazySingleton<_i3.Api>(() => _i3.Api());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i4.AppService>(() => _i4.AppService());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i5.DialogService>(
        () => thirdPartyServicesModule.dialogService);
    gh.singleton<_i6.MyOrganizationViewModel>(_i6.MyOrganizationViewModel());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i7.MyOrganizations>(() => _i7.MyOrganizations());
    gh.singleton<_i8.MyOrganizationsSearchViewModel>(
        _i8.MyOrganizationsSearchViewModel());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i9.MyParticipations>(() => _i9.MyParticipations());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i5.NavigationService>(
        () => thirdPartyServicesModule.navigationService);
    gh.lazySingleton<_i10.NotificationsBadges>(
        () => _i10.NotificationsBadges());
    gh.singleton<_i11.OnboardingViewModel>(_i11.OnboardingViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i12.OrganizationAlertsViewModel>(
        _i12.OrganizationAlertsViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i13.OrganizationWithPostsViewModel>(
        _i13.OrganizationWithPostsViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i14.ParticipationsViewModel>(_i14.ParticipationsViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i15.QuestionViewModel>(_i15.QuestionViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i16.QuestionsListViewModel>(_i16.QuestionsListViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i17.ReportCreateViewModel>(_i17.ReportCreateViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i18.ReportViewModel>(_i18.ReportViewModel());
    gh.singleton<_i19.ReportsViewModel>(_i19.ReportsViewModel());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i20.Settings>(() => _i20.Settings());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i5.SnackbarService>(
        () => thirdPartyServicesModule.snackbarService);
    gh.singleton<_i21.SurveysListViewModel>(_i21.SurveysListViewModel());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i22.SurveysService>(() => _i22.SurveysService());
    gh.lazySingleton<_i23.TextToSpeech>(() => _i23.TextToSpeech());
    gh.singleton<_i24.UserViewModel>(_i24.UserViewModel());
    return this;
  }
}

class _$ThirdPartyServicesModule extends _i25.ThirdPartyServicesModule {
  @override
  _i5.NavigationService get navigationService => _i5.NavigationService();
  @override
  _i5.DialogService get dialogService => _i5.DialogService();
  @override
  _i5.SnackbarService get snackbarService => _i5.SnackbarService();
}
```

I have found that if i deplace this line up:

```
gh.lazySingleton<_i5.NavigationService>(
            () => thirdPartyServicesModule.navigationService);
```

the problem disappear but is replace with another error:

> Failed assertion: line 372 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null':
> Object/factory with  type MyOrganizations is not registered inside
> GetIt

my_organizations_viewmodel.dart:

```
@singleton
class MyOrganizationViewModel extends StreamViewModel<List<Organization>> {
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
  final _organizationsService = locator<MyOrganizations>();
...
```

my_organizations.dart:

```
@lazySingleton
class MyOrganizations with ListenableServiceMixin {
  final _settingsService = locator<Settings>();
  final _apiService = locator<Api>();
...
```

I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days and I've looked at a considerable number of posts, without finding any solutions.

Any idea is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by reordering the declarations in the file generated by injectable_generator and by modifying certain classes which declared a service.

I declared this service `late` and I initialized it in an initialization function called at runtime